# Passing arrays to Cuda

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, cuda

Hallo,

I am new to CUDA and im trying to copy an array of data into the CUDA kernel. Im not sure what I am doing wrong and could really do with some pointers in the right direction.

My UpdatePixel function works if I dont use the array to set the data. If I set colour.x to 1 my whole screen goes red. If I use m_dataPtr[index] as colour.x only a few pixels towards the bottom of the screen goes red (less then 5 pixels). I have attached the cuda code an the c++ code that I think would be relewant. As the code works fine with colour.x = 1, i suspect its the copy//allocation part of the cuda code that is broken?

CUDA:

```
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <cutil_math.h>

__constant__ float* m_dataPtr; 

__device__ unsigned int rgbaFloatToInt_new(float4 rgba)
{
    rgba.x = __saturatef(rgba.x);   // clamp to [0.0, 1.0]
    rgba.y = __saturatef(rgba.y);
    rgba.z = __saturatef(rgba.z);
    rgba.w = __saturatef(rgba.w);
    return (uint(rgba.w*255)<<24) | (uint(rgba.z*255)<<16) | (uint(rgba.y*255)<<8) | uint(rgba.x*255);
}

__global__ void UpdatePixel(unsigned int *outputImage, unsigned int imageW, unsigned int imageH)
{
    uint x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    uint y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int index = y * imageW + x;

    float data = m_dataPtr[index];
    float4 colour;
    colour.x = data;
    colour.y = 0;
    colour.z = 0;
    colour.w = 1;

    outputImage[index] = rgbaFloatToInt_new(colour); 
}

extern "C" void UpdateImage(dim3 gridSize, dim3 blockSize,uint *d_output, uint imageW, uint imageH)
{
    UpdatePixel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>( d_output, imageW, imageH);
}

extern "C" void AllocateData(size_t dataSize)
{
    cudaFree(m_dataPtr);
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&m_dataPtr, dataSize) );
}

extern "C" void CopyData(float *dataPtr, size_t dataSize)
{
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(m_dataPtr, dataPtr, dataSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
}
```

C++:

```
    float *pixelData = new float[imageWidth * imageHeight];
    unsigned int pixelDataSize = (sizeof(float) * imageWidth * imageHeight);

    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
    {
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
        {
            unsigned int idx = imageWidth * y + x;
            pixelData[idx] = 1;
        }
    }

    AllocateData(pixelDataSize);
    CopyData(pixelData, pixelDataSize);
```

Comment: Please show the code where you call UpdateImage(). In particular, where is the memory that d_output points to ?

Comment: Post how you build the grid for the kernel, and how you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using constant memory on the gpu, you will need to use cudaMemcpyToSymbol rather than cudaMemcpy.